# ansible delete file on remote server

Tags: ansible

I am not able to delete files from remote machine through file absent command -

```
  - name: Removing existing export file with same name
    file: 
      path: '/path/{{ item.Export_FileName }} ' 
      state: absent
    delegate_to: remote_server   
    with_items: "{{ my_items.array }}
```

command runs successfully but not deleting the files

Comment: I am guessing it has to do with your path and with_items. Try to debug it.

Comment: In the path it showing the correct filename "path": "/path/filename ", "state": "absent"

Comment: you have a space after the filename

Comment: thanks soo much !! it worked

Comment: Glad it worked.

Comment: why downvote man :( ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a space in the path after the filename